# Bigcommerce API - getting order lines

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I have a question concerning the retrieval of order line (order products) from bigcommerce api.
In the documentation there is a description of how to retrieve a list of orders. Each of those orders has a url pointing to order products (that is what I want). But in order to retrieve those order lines for a big list of orders I need to make an API call for each of those orders.

My question:
Is there some other way to retrieve order lines for a big list of orders without separate call to order products for each order?

Comment: I don't think so. I think you're going to have to loop through all of the orders using a separate call for each to get the necessary product details.

Comment: that's what I was worried about...